# swift 3 .all was deprecated - drag and drop nstableview

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

I have a working `NSTableView` drag and drop solution.
but I get a warning message for this code part:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row: Int, proposedDropOperation operation: NSTableViewDropOperation) -> NSDragOperation {
        if operation == .above {
            return .move
        }
        return .all
    }
```

> 'all' was deprecated in OS X 10.10

what I have to use instead of `.all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdragoperation/1416006-all_obsolete):

> The `NSDragOperationAll` constant is deprecated. Use `every` instead.

Therefore, use:

```
return .every
```